# Removing the aside in vitepress

Tags: vue.js, vite, vuepress, vitepress

Feeling really silly right now, but for whatever reason I cannot get this aside to go away in my vitepress docs.

The [docs say](https://vitepress.vuejs.org/config/frontmatter-configs.html#aside) that I just need to add `aside: false` and it should be gone, but mine is still there for some reason. Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the route of your page on the browser ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment!
This is a 'feature' of vitepress it seems and you can't/couldn't (havent been using it for a while now) get rid of the aside. I've worked around it now, but thank you!

Comment: Welcome, I have it working locally by using yaml aside variable! and removed by setting it to false.

Comment: Cheers! I will definitely be using it in the future so this will be a good reference. Thanks!